# Aerospike - How to convert BinMap to JSON using golang driver

Tags: aerospike

The data fetched from database is always of the type:

```
map[interface{}]interface{}
```

This type is not supported by json.Marshal() function in go. What is the best way to get JSON from the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinMap` is basically a `map[string]interface{}`. That is not your problem.

Your issue seems to be that you have bins which are maps, and since maps are represented as `map[interface{}]interface{}` and those are not supported by `json.Marshal`, you are getting an error.

The easiest workaround is to use `github.com/json-iterator/go` as a drop-in replacement, which supports marshaling of `map[interface{}]interface{}`.